# Missing Double Quotes in the output when using FileWriter

Tags: java, file

```
"Mr","Sis",Yakkozz,M,10.05.1971,NR128584B,Lminltzkqu@aviva.com,1 Launceston Terrace,St. Marychurch Road,,,,NR1 2HJ,RQF,Phillips Petroleum Co,Worcestershire,A.
```

this is my input which has double quotes in the first two columns

**but the out put is like**

```
Mr,Sibus,Yakkozz,M,12.05.1971,NR828584B,avivanfttestLminltzkqu@aviva.com,1 Launceston Terrace,St. Marychurch Road,,,,NR2 2HJ,RQF,Phillips Petroleum Co,Worcestershire,A
```

**This is the code which is doing it :**

```
String collect = (String) csv.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
                    writer.write(collect);
```

The value of *collect* if i inspect is correct with double quotes in the first two columns but outfile doesn't contain the quotes

Comment: ..what is `csv`?

Comment: @Berger `writer` seems to be a `FileWriter` as stated in the title

Comment: You can't seriously beleve that FileWriter does this. Clearly you aren't sending them to it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Java is interpreting your input as a simple string. Try using `"\"Mr\""` The outermost quotations tell Java that it is a string, and the `\"` is the escape code to use double quotes within strings.